# Writing regex result into a new file

Tags: ruby, regex, stdout

I've got a list of devices:

- ipc-bei640-r-br-01
- ipc-bei640-r-br-02
- ipc-bei640-r-br-03
- ipc-bei640-r-br-04
- ipc-bei640-r-br-05
- ipc-bem640-r-br-01
- ipc-bem640-r-br-02
- ipc-bem640-r-br-03
- ipc-crg660-r-br-02
- ipc-geb680-r-br-04
- ipc-lgv630-r-br-01

This small little ruby script counts the lines of the file braslist.txt scans it with a regex and writes the results to a newfile called "strippedfile.txt"

```
lines = IO.readlines("/usr/local/bin/braslist.txt")

# Linecount is forwarded to StdOut.
puts lines.length

str = File.read('braslist.txt')

file_name = ['strippedfile.txt']

file_name.each do |file_name|
  text = File.read(file_name)
  new_contents = str.scan(/^ipc-(?<bng>[a-z]{3}\d{3})-r-br(?<nr>-\d{2})$/)

# open and write to a file with ruby
open('strippedfile.txt', 'w') { |f|
  f.print new_contents
}

end
```

Now what i cant seem to fix, is in the new file "strippedfile" the results are always ["bei640", "-01"]  ["bei640", "-02"] ["bei640", "-03"]

And i am trying to get all results in this format:

- bei640-01
- bei640-02
- bei640-03
- bei640-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan` returns an array of matches, you probably want to `join` them:

```
- new_contents = str.scan(/^ipc-(?<bng>[a-z]{3}\d{3})-r-br(?<nr>-\d{2})$/)
+ new_contents = str.scan(/^ipc-(?<bng>[a-z]{3}\d{3})-r-br(?<nr>-\d{2})$/).map(&:join)

To print everything without quotes and brackets line by line:

- f.print new_contents
+ f.puts new_contents
```

Comment: For what do the -/+ stand for?

Comment: It’s a standard git/mercurial/svn syntax for removed/added lines.

Comment: Ah nvm i understand :)

Comment: Ok it looks much better than before, but is there a way i can remove the " and ,  and list the devices each line by line? 

File looks like this:
["bei640-01", "bei640-02", "bei640-03", "bei640-04", "bei640-05", "bem640-01", "bem640-02",

Comment: Sure. Change `f.print new_contents` to `f.puts new_contents`.

Comment: Great, just what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your resultant array is

```
a = [["bei640", "-02"], ["bei640", "-03"]]
```

You can use `join` to get your desired result

```
a.map{|i| i.join } #=> ["bei640-02", "bei640-03"]
```

or use shortcut as `mudasobwa` answered

```
a.map(&:join) #=> ["bei640-02", "bei640-03"]
```